# Installing pr2_mechanism_msgs: is the hg repository down?

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, kforge, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install the pr2simulator stack which requires [pr2mechanism](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism?distro=groovy), which in turn requires [pr2_mechanism_msgs](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism_msgs). This is what I tried:

```
cd ros_ws
rosws set pr2_mechanism_msgs --hg https://kforge.ros.org/pr2mechanism/hg
rosws update pr2_mechanism_msgs
```

This doesn't seem to work. The kforge.ros.org site looks down. I found the pr2simulator stack on github, but pr2_mechanism_msgs isn't hosted there. Can someone please tell me how to get this working? Is there an alternate hosting location?

I tried an hg clone command too and it doesn't work. http://isup.me/kforge.ros.org says the site is down.

I'm on Fedora 18: I must install these from source.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60212/installing-pr2_mechanism_msgs:-is-the-hg-repository-down?/) by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2013-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) on 2013-04-08**:
I found this question which is about the same thing, but the answer was to install the deb file which doesn't apply to me: http://answers.ros.org/question/48992/missing-package-pr2_mechanism_msgs-in-pr2_mechanism-stack/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was down. Also, the hg URL is https://kforge.ros.org/pr2mechanism/pr2_mechanism_msgs, not just https://kforge.ros.org/pr2mechanism/hg as listed on the wiki page.

```
$ rosws set pr2_mechanism_msgs --hg https://kforge.ros.org/pr2mechanism/pr2_mechanism_msgs
```

---

Originally posted by [FranciscoD](https://answers.ros.org/users/3235/franciscod/) with karma: 128 on 2013-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2